# R-How to calculate year of birth given age and date of visit

Tags: r

I have a data set like this

```
Age    Date of visit
28     2015-03-28 17:51:31 CET
26     2015-03-28 18:40:11 CET
```

how do I calculate the DOB based on the above information.

Comment: Could also try `with(df, as.POSIXlt(Dateofvisit)$year + 1900L - Age)` using base

Comment: I couldn't get the code to work.

Comment: do you have some trailing characters in your column names? perhaps offer the `dput()`of your table?

Comment: What are you real column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
d1 <- ymd_hms("2015-03-28 17:51:31 CET")
d1
[1] "2015-03-28 17:51:31 UTC"
d1 - years(28)
[1] "1987-03-28 17:51:31 UTC"
```

Not sure you want that precision with the time etc, but that can be removed

Comment: Everything except the year will be probably wrong, unless you will assume each user visits the site exactly at the time the nurse screamed "*push!!*" to his mother x years ago. In many cases even the year will wrong.

Comment: Thanks but I got numeric(0) by running the following code  n1=mn$DXSTDTC-mn$age

Comment: @David Yup. Hard to fix that without knowing more about the age